# Store Multidimensional checkbox in database

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I want to store checkbox in database.. but the checkbox is a bit complex than regular. 
Basically [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRoHa.png) is what I want to implement.

I am able to collect data from input and store it in an array, but I am not able to display it in sequence.
[Example of inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GLb0.png) that I give.
Then this is what I get when I print_r() the array:

```
Array ( [aadhar] => Array ( [original] => 1 ) [pan] => Array ( [original] => 1 ) [address] => Array ( [xerox] => 1 ) [lightbill] => Array ( [original] => 1 ) )
```

My HTML code.

```
 <table>
      <tr>
      <td>Aadhar</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="document[aadhar][original]" value="1"/></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="document[aadhar][xerox]" value="1"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Pan Card</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="document[pan][original]" value="1"/></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="document[pan][xerox]" value="1"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="document[address][original]" value="1"/></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="document[address][xerox]" value="1"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>Light Bill</td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="document[lightbill][original]" value="1"/></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="document[lightbill][xerox]" value="1"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <tr>
      <td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

PROBLEM:
After the user click submit, I want to show him, his selection,(like a confirmation).
Example:

```
Document Selected
----------------- 
Adhaar - Original 
Pan card - Original
Address - xerox 
Light bill - Original
```

How should I do it? I tried foreach() but not working. 
Even when I try to simple display like **echo document[adhaar][orginal];** still it shows error!

Comment: What is the error it is showing?

Comment: foreach ($document as $name => $nvalue) {
      echo $name."<br>";
      foreach ($name as $type => $tvalue) {
        echo $tvalue;
      }
    }

**Invalid argument in foreach()**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: Do you mean to be using [radio buttons](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p10.html) instead?  If the person should only be able to choose Original OR Xerox per row, you might want radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

That said, if you do want checkboxes, the output PHP would be something like:

```
<?php

// loops through each "document" value in the POST
foreach($_POST['document'] as $key => $val) {
    echo $key; // print the key for each value in document (what you treat as a "row"
    foreach($val as $k => $v) {
       echo " - ".$k; // print EACH value within that key (what you thread as a "column"
    }
    echo "<br/>\n"; // after all columns per row are printed, print a line break
}
```

Here is a link to a working example:
http://myingling.com/random/random/44477622/

Some things worth reading about:

1. [associative arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)
2. [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) (especially using the `$key => $val` structure)
3. the [`key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) function

Comment: No cant use radio, I am assigned a task by a company, and they need checkbox

Comment: And yes, that is what I want :) , How did you get it? Can you please update your answer?

Comment: What do you mean?  The answer already has the code from the site I made, and the site I made has the same code on it as well.  (The HTML is yours, just in the `<form>` wrapper.  You can right-click "View Source" to see the HTML.)

Comment: I imagine it would work that way -- can you share your whole code please?

Comment: yes sorry, its working :) earlier I didnt use foreach() the right way. thanks alot! :) there are no more doubts, everythings working as expected. :)

Comment: Sorry to bother you again :( I just found out,  the foreach it displays correctly for only one check.either original or xerox. 
When I check both, original and xerox, then foreach doesnt display both, only displays one. What should I do? I tried modifiying foreach.. with whatever little knowledge I have...still I couldnt get it right.

Comment: I assume you mean "incorrectly"?  Share your whole code for me to find the bug.

Comment: ohkk should make a new topic or just post it here in comments?

Comment: If it's related to this, post it here; if it's a different issue from this subject of this question, create a new one.

Comment: You can also check your code, http://myingling.com/random/random/44477622/ 
If you check both, of same document, still it displays only one

Comment: Ahhhh, you never gave an example of BOTH selected, so that requirement wasn't clear.  Edited the answer and the code on my server both.  Should handle that case now.

Comment: ahh sorry I missed to mention it earlier. Thanks alot once again.

Comment: No problem.  If the answer is correct, don't forget to both upvote and accept.  Also: studying up on multidimensional arrays sounds like it will help you a lot for doing PHP work in the future.  I'd suggest watching a few YouTube videos on the subject.

Comment: Yes I need it, just that I dont have much experience working on it. I would have done it already.. but I am not allowed to upvote. I am new account.

Comment: No worries.  A lot of people here have been kinda strict with "this is a duplicate question" and trying to shut down the newbies because THEY (the old-timers) know the answers, but often the newbies don't even know what to ask.  That's why I'm trying to guide you to the terms you need to study and such.  No worries on upvotes, but accepting answers helps close issues which means others won't try to answer closed issues.

Comment: Yes exactly. Really helped me alot.